# jQuery dropdown change on nested form with Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the nested_form gem on Rails 3.1.1 app with jQuery. In the attempt to build some dynamic select menus I'm stuck at the first step.

First, I want to test change value detection in drop down however name keeps changing. When I inspect through browser inspector I get a new ID every time I refresh like `order_items_attributes_new_1319384594266_product_id`.

In my JS file I have

```
jQuery('select').change(function() {

alert("test");
});
```

which triggers when simple drop down changes but not on nested form drop downs. Why? How can I make sure name is fixed or how to select nested form drop downs?

Comment: i am not familiar with RoR but it you can use classes or id to identify the `select`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can start by following this tutorial which explains the process.
http://www.petermac.com/rails-3-jquery-and-multi-select-dependencies/

then when you will try to apply the tutorial logic in your version, 
The partial which is rendered using jquery should contain something like this:

Example in HAML:

```
= semantic_fields_for "order[items_attributes][]", order do |form|
  = form.input :blah
```

Hope that helps or at least gives you an indication :)